# jQuery SHOW / HIDE slide image with 'auto width'

Tags: jquery, css, width, show-hide

I have some problem with CSS and jQuery..
I try slide image to hide, change src and show with slide... Everything is ok when I use exacly parametrs 'width' e.g. 500 px, or 50% but I need width:auto and height 100%..

Code CSS

```
#gallery img {
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
    max-width:auto;
    margin:0 auto;
    display:block;
    border:none;
}

#gallery { 
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    height:auto;
    top:140px;
    bottom:60px;
    margin:0 auto;
    display: block;
    z-index:10;
    overflow:none;
}
```

and jQuery

```
$('#gallery').hide("slide", { direction: "left" }, 1000);
$('.gallery_img').attr('src', url);
$('#gallery').show("slide", { direction: "right" }, 1000);
```

I google chrome everything is OK, but IE and firefox dosen't support this, image when in static have correct proportions but when startting slide width changes to natural size IMG...

Have any solutions for this problem ?
Thanks

Comment: May you please setup a http://jsFiddle.net or http://jsBin.com to play with? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to set that w/Jquery, not css. If you set width to 100% in css, that's what it will be...100%.